Ollama OpenWebUI (TOOLS) connect to a ssh server and give me the output of command?
I am doing a project to ollama help me to maintain a Linux infrastructure, and need the IA to connect to a given ssh server with given credentials and execute a command and bring the output of command to the chat.
I already did this code, but it's not working, somethings (depending how I ask the prompt) I can see the ssh connection on the server, but no return of output.
This is the tool code I am using:
"""
title: ssh connection
description 
"""
    
import os
import requests
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
import paramiko

class Tools:
    class Valves(BaseModel):
        SSH_HOST: str = Field(
            default="111.111.111.111", description="Adress to connect to ssh"
        )
        SSH_USERNAME: str = Field(
            default="adminuser", description="Username to use on ssh server"
        )
        SSH_PASSWORD: str = Field(
            default="thePassword123!", description="Password to connect on ssh server"
        )

    pass

    class UserValves(BaseModel):
        SSH_COMMAND: str = Field(
            default="ifconfig",
            description="user given command trought the chat",
        )

    pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.citation = True
        self.Valves = self.Valves()
        pass
        # pass

    def connect_ssh(
        self, ssh_ip: str, ssh_username: str, ssh_password: str, ssh_command: str
    ) -> str:
        """
        create a ssh connection using the data the user entered on the prompt,
        This is the way you can connect to a ssh server, get the ssh_ip, ssh_username, ssh_password and ssh_command from the user prompt em use it to call the function paramiko.
        use the bellow function to connect ssh servers and do what the user are asking

        :param: ssh_command Command to be executed on ssh connection
        :param: ssh_username username to log in in to ssh server
        :param: ssh_password password to use on log in to ssh server
        :param: ssh_host hostname or ip to open ssh connection
        :output: A string containing the output got after command issued, and will be returned to user.
        """

        """
        check if the informations for connect ssh is fullfilled
        """
        if not self.Valves.SSH_IP:
            return "Let the user know the ip to ssh connection was not provided. User will tell the ssh_host trought chat"  ###

        if not self.Valves.SSH_USERNAME:
            return "Let the user know the username to ssh connection was not provided. User will tell the ssh_username trought chat"

        if not self.Valves.SSH_PASSWORD:
            return "Let the user know the password was not provided. User will tell the ssh_password trought chat"

        if not self.UserValves.SSH_COMMAND:
            return "Let the user know the ssh command was not provided. User will tell the ssh_command trought chat"

        """
        use this function to connect to a ssh server, using parameters given by the user 
        """
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(
            self.UserValves.SSH_IP,
            username=self.Valves.SSH_USERNAME,
            password=self.Valves.SSH_PASSWORD,
        )
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(self.UserValves.SSH_COMMAND)

        """
        get the output of the command and return to the chat.
        """
        if stdout:
            output += stdout.read().decode()
        if stderr:
            output += stderr.read().decode()
        return "say that the command was executed, and you are waiting the output to tell on chat"
        ssh.close()
        return output


can you reformat your code

didnt saw that, code is formated.

Hi , thank you for reformatting it, is this the actual code you wrote for it or a pseudo code? I have provided an answer let's see what happens.

this is the code i wrote for it.

I didnt trigger the tool yet, trying to figure out why.
The response from AI is "i cant do a ssh conection...."
Iam intense working on this, I will give you a feedback as soon I got a result.
Thanks alot for your time.

take all the time you want, i am always happy to help.

I think you are on the right track, here are some issues I could see
Issues:

You have incorrect object reference for all your initialized variables: In your code there is a reference to self.UserValves.SSH_IP, which is incorrect because SSH_IP is not defined in UserValves. It should reference self.Valves.SSH_HOST instead.

You have an incorrect variable usage: You did not initialize your output variable before using it to retrieve stdout and stderr outputs.


I have made the necessary corrections, Here is a revised code, it should guide you to solve the problem. I hope it helps ypu.
import os
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
import paramiko

class Tools:
    class Valves(BaseModel):
        SSH_HOST: str = Field(
            default="111.11.111.111", description="Address to connect to SSH"
        )
        SSH_USERNAME: str = Field(
            default="adminuser", description="Username to use on SSH server"
        )
        SSH_PASSWORD: str = Field(
            default="thePassword123123", description="Password to connect on SSH server"
        )

    class UserValves(BaseModel):
        SSH_COMMAND: str = Field(
            default="ifconfig",
            description="User-given command through the chat",
        )

    def __init__(self):
        self.citation = True
        self.Valves = self.Valves()
        self.UserValves = self.UserValves()

    def connect_ssh(self) -> str:
        """
        create a ssh connection using the data the user entered on the prompt,
        This is the way you can connect to a ssh server, get the ssh_ip, ssh_username, ssh_password and ssh_command from the user prompt em use it to call the function paramiko.
        use the bellow function to connect ssh servers and do what the user are asking

        :param: ssh_command Command to be executed on ssh connection
        :param: ssh_username username to log in in to ssh server
        :param: ssh_password password to use on log in to ssh server
        :param: ssh_host hostname or ip to open ssh connection
        :output: A string containing the output got after command issued, and will be returned to user.
        """

        """
        check if the informations for connect ssh is fullfilled
        """
        if not self.Valves.SSH_HOST:
            return "Let the user know the ip to ssh connection was not provided. User will tell the ssh_host trought chat"  ###


        if not self.Valves.SSH_USERNAME:
            return "Let the user know the username to ssh connection was not provided. User will tell the ssh_username trought chat"

        if not self.Valves.SSH_PASSWORD:
           return "Let the user know the username to ssh connection was not provided. User will tell the ssh_username trought chat"

        if not self.UserValves.SSH_COMMAND:
            return "Let the user know the ssh command was not provided. User will tell the ssh_command thought chat"


        try:
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(
                self.Valves.SSH_HOST,
                username=self.Valves.SSH_USERNAME,
                password=self.Valves.SSH_PASSWORD,
            )
     
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(self.UserValves.SSH_COMMAND)

            # Read output
            output = ""
            if stdout:
                output += stdout.read().decode()
            if stderr:
                output += stderr.read().decode()
                
            # Close SSH connection
            ssh.close()
            
            if output.strip():
                return output
            else:
                return "command worked, but no output "
            
        except Exception as e:
            return f"Error: {str(e)}"



I think the Python code is correct(Derek made it better), but I'am with problem to make the ollama run the paramiko part of the code. When I ask on the prompt to make de ssh connection it simulate one or just say cant do it. The correct behavior must be execute the paramiko part and return the output to chat.

@Pedro can I suggest you use see link->  crew-ai to run the ssh rather than ollama doing all the work dedicate another agent for the ssh bit instead of ollama or another model?

I could test and even saying that its not possible open a ssh connection, the paramiko is being called (I can see the ssh connection comming on the server) but the return is not show. How do I can make the llama know that with this he is ssh capable ?

Did you train the model at all or it is out of the box(like you just downloaded it)? which model are you using llama3? maybe the remote server you are using has restrictions have you tried if you can ssh into it without using ollama?

Yes, Iam using out of box llama3, the ssh is working, when I try the python on linux CLI it works perfectly, I think the problem is I dont know how to parametrize the OpenWebUI TOOL to do what I want, I think its a prompt question more than code by now.

can you try langchain tools instead they are very helpful. Another solution if you want to use openwebuitool is to pass a python script for the ollama to run via   like this await __event_emitter__({"type":subprocess.run(command=ssh into machine, shell=True, check=True) , "data":{"content": "This message will be appended to the chat."}})
